# Flutter crashes on startup when published to testflight

Tags: flutter, testflight

Our app runs fine on iOS simulator and physical hardware when run from VSCode.  When we compile an ipa, load to TestFlight, and install, it crashes immediately on load.  We created a new Fluter app (the default counter app) and that has the same issue.

```
Incident Identifier: 2E9C433A-6972-4119-B1E3-F56963B338E6
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,7
Process:             Runner [2791]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FAE683F5-FC78-4DA9-A0FC-08FCE3894A38/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.btrsoftware.hello
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
AppStoreTools:       15A240a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,7:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.btrsoftware.hello [1257]

Date/Time:           2023-09-27 00:14:32.5275 -0700
Launch Time:         2023-09-27 00:14:32.3987 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.6.1 (20G81)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.80.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [2791]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage



Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001f62dd578 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000217158118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001be848178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000103cb0ed0 fml::KillProcess() + 12 (logging.cc:143)
4   Flutter                         0x0000000103cb1000 fml::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 4 (logging.cc:130)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000103cb1000 fml::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 304 (logging.cc:74)
6   Flutter                         0x0000000103eaa508 DartVMInitializer::Initialize(Dart_InitializeParams*) + 100 (dart_vm_initializer.cc:22)
7   Flutter                         0x0000000103eaa508 flutter::DartVM::DartVM(std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::DartVMData const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::IsolateNameServer>) + 3968 (dart_vm.cc:440)
8   Flutter                         0x0000000103eaa508 flutter::DartVM::DartVM(std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::DartVMData const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::IsolateNameServer>) + 3968 (dart_vm.cc:280)
9   Flutter                         0x0000000103eaa508 flutter::DartVM::Create(flutter::Settings, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::IsolateNameServer>) + 7964 (dart_vm.cc:262)
10  Flutter                         0x0000000103d13844 flutter::DartVMRef::Create(flutter::Settings, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>) + 524 (dart_vm_lifecycle.cc:77)
11  Flutter                         0x0000000103d13844 flutter::Shell::Create(flutter::PlatformData const&, flutter::TaskRunners, flutter::Settings, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformView, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Platfo... + 692 (shell.cc:142)
12  Flutter                         0x00000001039d7d20 -[FlutterEngine createShell:libraryURI:initialRoute:] + 1144 (FlutterEngine.mm:654)
13  Flutter                         0x00000001039ee410 -[FlutterViewController sharedSetupWithProject:initialRoute:] + 412 (FlutterViewController.mm:216)
14  Flutter                         0x00000001039ee24c -[FlutterViewController awakeFromNib] + 88 (FlutterViewController.mm:186)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9618c90 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1740 (UINib.m:391)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b96172d8 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 236 (UIStoryboard.m:233)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9617114 -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 80 (UIStoryboard.m:212)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b96271e8 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 140 (UIApplication.m:5017)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9760e5c -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 156 (UIApplication.m:5095)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b96d96c0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 688 (UIApplication.m:4752)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b96d93b4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:451)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9421664 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b975f850 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:567)
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9611c5c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:516)
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9611a84 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 620 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:566)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9611634 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:469)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9611500 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 148 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:73)
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9cfea68 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:54)
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9d9d074 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:27)
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b94bec70 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b99301ac __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.223 + 556 (UIScene.m:2007)
32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b958fc60 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216 (UIScene.m:1683)
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b958fad0 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244 (UIScene.m:1969)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b958f028 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 520 (UIApplication.m:4231)
35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b958edb4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:47)
36  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd39c2e4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 344 (FBSScene.m:440)
37  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3dc068 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.80 + 120 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:394)
38  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3a0120 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168 (FBSWorkspace.m:359)
39  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3dbcc0 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 360 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:393)
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001be7e7eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
41  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001be7eb91c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264 (queue.c:496)
42  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3aa24c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
43  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3a9de8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220 (FBSSerialQueue.m:181)
44  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001cd3ac694 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FBSSerialQueue.m:194)
45  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b73ea128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
46  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b73f67b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
47  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b737b648 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340 (CFRunLoop.c:2046)
48  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b73910d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
49  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b73963ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
50  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f28ac35c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
51  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9722f58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3782)
52  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9722bbc UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5372)
53  Runner                          0x0000000102ed81fc main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
54  dyld                            0x00000001d68c8dec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)
```

Flutter Doctor

`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.5 on channel stable at /Users/terry/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12fccda598 (8 days ago), 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
    • Engine revision bd986c5ed2
    • Dart version 3.1.2
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/terry/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/terry/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • D62D9057-93CF-4A1F-9E8B-84C3FC250876 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.92

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.`
```

Tried with previous Flutter version 3.13.4 with same crash on load.

Comment: Have you tested your app on a physical device in both debug and release mode? https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and my app is working on my iPhone with iOS 17.0.1 (I tried to run the release and debug version from Xcode, also the TestFlight version works fine on this device). However, the devices that have lower versions or any other versions cause problems and crashes immediately (I only tested from TestFlight).

*Edit 02 October 2023:*

I found out that the problem occurred due to the `connectivity_plus` package. If you are using `connectivity_plus`, you should make sure that the **minimum iOS deployment** is `12.0`

And update your **Podfile** like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      end
  end
end
```

Check this out: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2162#issuecomment-1738265666